# Поиск изображений при помощи команды

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Мне необходима помощь от вас. Я хотел бы разузнать, как написать код для бота, который по команде, например .cat, искал картинку с котами и отправлял в чат. Я гуглил по поводу этого, но не нашёл ничего мне понятного.

Comment: Могу посоветовать API для поиска разных картинок, мемов, артов

Comment: Я не против, желательно ещё бы разобраться как это API использовать)

Comment: С помощью библиотеки request доставать силку и потом вставлять в Embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример кода:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json


    
@client.command()
async def fox(self, ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/fox')# Здесь силка на картинки 
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Лисичка..., няя!',
        colour = discord.Color.blue()
        )
    embed.set_image(
        url = json_data['link']
        )
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

По этой [ссылке](https://some-random-api.ml) вы можете посмотреть больше API для картинок, вам надо будет просто нажать на Link to Api и потом скопировать адрес сайта и вставить его сюда:

```
response = requests.get('адрес_сайта')
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень сильно помогли мне =)

Comment: Пожалуйста, могу дать еще один API, если хотите

Comment: Нет, спасибо. Я уже нашёл необходимое мне API.